# findById returns null on hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following dart class which loads an object and an image. When I perform hot reload, the function findById returns an error message `Bad State: No element`. Upon debugging, I see that the list that I am querying on is null once I do a hot realod. I want to know why that happens and how do I fix this?

```
class ProductDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   static const routeName = '/product-detail';

  @override
  _ProductDetailScreenState createState() => _ProductDetailScreenState();
}

class _ProductDetailScreenState extends State<ProductDetailScreen> {
 var loadedProduct; 
 var productId;
 var _isLoading; 
  var _imageUrl;
  var cartId; 
  var imagePath = '';
   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createCartId();
  }
   
   Future<void> createCartId()async {
        var id = await nanoid(10);
        cartId = id; 
   }

   Future<void> didChangeDependencies() async {
       productId = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String; 
       imagePath = productId;
       setState(() {
          _isLoading = true; 
       });
      
       final myCacheManager = MyCacheManager();
    await myCacheManager.cacheImage(imagePath).then((String imageUrl) {
      setState(() {
        _imageUrl = imageUrl;
         _isLoading = false; 
      });    
    });
  
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context,listen:false).findById(productId); 
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var userId = Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).userId;
     
    return !(_isLoading)?Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
         actions: null,
        title: Text(loadedProduct.title),
      ),
      body:
      CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: false,
      child:
      Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
              height: size.height * 0.35,
              width: double.infinity,
           child:_imageUrl != 'No picture loaded'?
           CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: _imageUrl,
                progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) => 
                 Center(child:Loading()),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
              )
            :Image.asset('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
      ),
        Expanded(
          child: ItemInfo(
          cartId,
          loadedProduct.id,
          loadedProduct.title,
          loadedProduct.price,
          loadedProduct.description,
          loadedProduct.categoryName, 
          loadedProduct.isAvailable),
        ),
      ],
    ))]))
    :Center(child:Loading());
  }
}

class ItemInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  
   ItemInfo(this.cartId,this.id,this.name,this.price,this.description,this.category,this.isAvailable);
  var id;
  var cartId;
  var name;
  var price;
  var description;
  var category;
  var isAvailable;

  @override
  _ItemInfoState createState() => _ItemInfoState();
}

class _ItemInfoState extends State<ItemInfo> {
 bool changePrice = false;
 List<String> selectedItems; 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.orange, spreadRadius: 1)],
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
          topRight: Radius.circular(30),
        ),
      ),
      child:
        Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            TitlePriceRating(
            name: widget.name,
            price: widget.price,
          ),        
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Here's the function function findById**

```
Product findById(String id) {
    
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }
```

Here's the function which sets the _items list:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts(String title) async {
    var encodedTitle = Uri.encodeComponent(title);  
    var url = 'https://mm-nn-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken';
    try {
        final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
        final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];

        if (extractedData == null || extractedData['error'] != null) {
          _items = loadedProducts;
          return _items;
     }
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
          id: prodId,
          title: prodData['title'],
          description: prodData['description'],
          price: prodData['price'],
          categoryName: prodData['categoryName'],
        ));
      });
     notifyListeners();  
      _items = loadedProducts; 
      return _items;
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
```

This function is called in a class called `ProductOverviewScreen` which then calls a class called `ProductGrid`. `ProductGrid` basically contains a listviewbuilder of the products. This class then calls `ProductItem` which is basically a single product in the product list. `ProductItem` contains a button which when clicked, calls `ProductDetailsScreen` which is the class causing the error.

Comment: Can you share the code where you query items and add to `_items` list?

Comment: I have added it, thanks.

Comment: You haven't shared where `fetchAndSetProducts` is called, that might be helpful

Comment: Please see my updates.

Comment: "Upon debugging, I see that the list that I am querying on is null once I do a hot realod." Specifically, is `_items` literally `null` or is it an empty list?  I assume you actually mean it's an empty list since `_items.firstWhere` would have resulted in a null pointer exception (reported as a `NoSuchMethod` error) if `_items` were `null`.

Comment: Also, since you know how to use the debugger, you should be able to figure out when and how `_items` becomes an empty list.  Is `fetchAndSetProducts` called?  If so, which code path is executed?  Is it what you expected?  If not, then what caused your code to go down the wrong path?

Answer (score 2):

Use setState method.

```
   Future<void> didChangeDependencies() async {
       setState(() {
          productId = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String; 
          imagePath = productId;
          _isLoading = true; 
       });
      
       final myCacheManager = MyCacheManager();
       await myCacheManager.cacheImage(imagePath).then((String imageUrl) {
          setState(() {
             _imageUrl = imageUrl;
             _isLoading = false; 
          });    
       });
    }
```

Comment: Putting it in setState won't work. I have tried it already. I want to understand why when you do a hot reload, you have to load all the documents again from the db and set it to _items object again. I really cannot understand why it behaves like that.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```dart
return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
```

with

```dart
return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id, orElse: () => null,);
```

Comment: That will mean that I return an empty item which will not render anything on screen. it will give me title was called on null error

Comment: Then return a default item in the orElse

Comment: Returning a default item will defeat the purpose.

Comment: I want to load the same exact product using the productId, not the default product

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this code.

```
 extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
    loadedProducts.add(Product(
      id: prodId,
      title: prodData['title'],
      description: prodData['description'],
      price: prodData['price'],
      categoryName: prodData['categoryName'],
    ));
  });
```

In this code, you are directly adding the product to the state. The state is immutable. So make a temporary list there add all the data into the temporary list and finally use **setState()** to put the temporary list data into the state. The code should be like this.

```
List<Product> tempList = [];
extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
    tempList.add(Product(
      id: prodId,
      title: prodData['title'],
      description: prodData['description'],
      price: prodData['price'],
      categoryName: prodData['categoryName'],
    ));
  });
setState((){
  loadedProducts = tempList;
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to use setState in a class implementing changenotifier?